# Как вывести значение поля, а не объект?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-orm

- Проект на Django
- Используется внешняя таблица от другого проекта (PostgreSQL) в Read-Only
- В таблицах, в качестве PrimaryKey используется текстовая строка "UUID" (вида: "abcdef-text-1r4trctstfytfuk2r"). Не спрашивайте, почему...

Окей, сделал модели, создал представление для вывода сообщений таблицей. Нужно чтобы в таблице отображалось имя автора в виде ссылки на страницу с персональной инфой о авторе.

Всё работает, но есть проблема и вопрос:

1. Django вместо ожидаемого Join'а (в sql) делает отдельные запросы в базу для каждого message (сотни SQL Запросов на страницу!). Почему так получилось и как это "вылечить"?
2. Как получить "Сырое" значение поля? `{{ message.author }}` - ожидаемо, вернет "Object что-то-там". А как получить саму строку, что хранится в соответствующей колонке таблицы?

Код примерно такой:

```python
class Author(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'external_author'


class Message(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, models.DO_NOTHING)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'external_message'


class Messages(ListView):
    model = Message
    paginate_by = 25
```

```html
{% for message in object_list %}
<a href="{{ url 'author_details' pk=message.author.uuid }}">{{ message.author.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, всё просто - достаточно дописать к интересующему полю "_id":

```html
{% for message in object_list %}
<a href="{{ url 'author_details' pk=message.author_id }}">{{ message.author.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}

--> {{ message.author_id }}
```

Остлось под вопросом, почему Django делает *prefetch_related* вместо *select_related*, когда обращаешся к полям с зависимостями.
Конечно, можно это обойти, явно указав *select_related()* в *View* -> *queryset* (или переопределив *get_queryset()*)... Но это костыль...

Comment: `django` не делает ни `prefetch_related` ни `select_related`, если только вы об этом явно не попросили. По умолчанию, запрос достает только сам объект без ассоциаций. Обращение к ассоциации делает новый запрос. Причина такого поведения, чтобы невинный запрос не прочитал целый граф объектов. Джанго не может догадаться в момент, когда нужно уже доставать первый объект, что вы будете с ним делать и к каким ассоциациям обращаться. Поэтому все подсказки, что загружать и этим улучшать производительность, нужно делать явно. Так что это не костыль - это нормально